# How to keep value in variable between page refreshes?

Tags: reactjs

Right now I have a project where I have a input on the landing page, on submit this input calls a another page and I need the value that was in the input to be displayed in the page called, even if page reloads.

I was trying to do this with useContext, but it doesn't work, the page loads correctly, but when I press `F5` the value passed down from the input to the second page is erased.

What possible solutions can I use to solve this?

Comment: You could use a cookie?

Comment: "between renders" is not the question you're wanting. You're wanting between page refreshes. They are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page reload restart the application from scratch.

There are several options where to store the state you want to keep:

- SessionSorage
- LocalStorage
- Cookies

IMHO, SessionStorage would make the most sense.

Global State libraries like Redux also have plugins to store state persistently.

Comment: thank you ...which one is better ?